# Change a color on flash importing an html from XML

Tags: html, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm getting an html text from a XML and I have to show a text in flash, I was able to print and the flash has interpreted the HTML but anything changed.

I already use the text.htmlText

EDIT:

this is how i get my HTML text...

```
tick.ticker.htmlText = EBFlash.browser.data("D_TICKER").texto
```

.texto returns

```
<p> LINHA 020<span style="color:#a52a2a;">-INTERBAIRROS</span> II (HOR&Aacute;RIO) - ALTERA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O DE HOR&Aacute;RIOS EM DIAS &Uacute;TEIS A PARTIR DE <b>13/01/2014 </b>- WWW.URBS.CURITIBA.PR.GOV.BR</p>
```

so the flash interprate the HTML but dont make the color changes or anything else.

Comment: What happens when you trace out your html string? Is it correct? Are you able to set the text field to some other value as a test?

Comment: Yes, is correct. when  I set other value works, but when I set the HTML from the XML nothing change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a stylesheet in Flash to actually style the span tags.  In the text that was returned from your xml you're going to need to replace the style attribute with a class name first, then style it:

```
var myText:String = EBFlash.browser.data("D_TICKER").texto;
myText = myText.replace( 'style="color:#a52a2a;"', 'class="colorText"' );
```

That should make your text look like:

```
<p> LINHA 020<span class="colorText">-INTERBAIRROS</span> II (HOR&Aacute;RIO) - ALTERA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O DE HOR&Aacute;RIOS EM DIAS &Uacute;TEIS A PARTIR DE <b>13/01/2014 </b>- WWW.URBS.CURITIBA.PR.GOV.BR</p>
```

then:

```
import flash.text.StyleSheet;
var myStyleSheet:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
myStyleSheet.setStyle( '.colorText', { color: '#a52a2a' } );
tick.ticker.styleSheet = myStyleSheet;

tick.ticker.htmlText = myText;
```

The BOLD tags will not work unless the font you are using has a bold option.  You can also replace the BOLD tags with another set of span tags and a unique class name and style them to be bold the same way the color is being styled above.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't already try something like...

```
yourTextFieldName.htmlText = xml.node.text()[0];
```

I'm a little confused as to what your actual problem is. If you could show us some code it would be easier to understand.

EDIT:
The code you pasted below doesn't look like properly formatted flash html. Flash is only capable of very basic styling. Read here...

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText

If you have access to the source try something like...

< font color="#a52a2a">-INTERBAIRROS </font>

You can also use style sheets in flash...
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html

Comment: tick.ticker.htmlText = EBFlash.browser.data("D_TICKER").texto -> this is from i get my HTML text...

XML return this for me:

<p>
LINHA 020<span style="color:#a52a2a;">-INTERBAIRROS</span> II (HOR&Aacute;RIO) - ALTERA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O DE HOR&Aacute;RIOS EM DIAS &Uacute;TEIS A PARTIR DE <b>13/01/2014 </b>- WWW.URBS.CURITIBA.PR.GOV.BR</p>

so the flash interprate the HTML but dont make the color changes or anything else.

Comment: please edit your question and put the code there... Not only will it be legible, but everyone will see it, and not just the readers of this answer.